Internal Docker network err: attempt to send data on a closed socket
Using openresty/openresty:latest in Dockerfile:
FROM openresty/openresty:latest

COPY default-prod.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y luarocks

RUN luarocks install luasocket
RUN luarocks install pgmoon
RUN luarocks install lua-cjson
RUN luarocks install lua-resty-openssl

and networks: in my docker-compose.yml
  smalljobsdb:
    image: postgres:14
    container_name: smalljobsdb
    env_file:
      - .env.production
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "5450:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./db-production/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - smalljobs

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    # network_mode: host
    networks:
      - smalljobs
    volumes:
      # - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./server/shared:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./nginx/cert:/etc/nginx/ssl:ro
      - storefrontbuild:/usr/share/nginx/html/storefront
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      smalljobsdb:
        condition: service_started
      smalljobsserver:
        condition: service_started
      smalljobsstorefront:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

when I try to connect to my postgres db during rendering my website in my nginx.conf file:
location ~ ^/[0-9]+$ {
        default_type text/html;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
        content_by_lua_block {
            local id = ngx.var.uri:match("^/([0-9]+)$")  -- Extract the ID from URI

            if id then
                local cjson = require "cjson"
                local pgmoon = require("pgmoon")
                
                -- Set up the PostgreSQL connection
                local pg = pgmoon.new({
                    host     = "smalljobsdb",
                    port     = "", << DELETED BUT ITS USED
                    user     = "", << DELETED BUT ITS USED
                    password = "", << DELETED BUT ITS USED
                    database = ""  << DELETED BUT ITS USED
                })

                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "BEFORE CONNECTION " .. id)
                -- Connect to the PostgreSQL database
                assert(pg:connect())
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "AFTER CONNECTION " .. id)
                pg:keepalive()

I get err:
nginx                  | 2024/11/08 17:09:27 [error] 7#7: *1 [lua] default.conf:60):17: BEFORE CONNECTION 8, client: 85.193.34.174, server: smalljobs.cz, request: "GET /8 HTTP/1.1", host: "smalljobs.cz"
nginx                  | 2024/11/08 17:09:28 [error] 7#7: *1 [lua] default.conf:60):20: AFTER CONNECTION 8, client: 85.193.34.174, server: smalljobs.cz, request: "GET /8 HTTP/1.1", host: "smalljobs.cz"
nginx                  | 2024/11/08 17:09:28 [error] 7#7: *1 attempt to send data on a closed socket: u:00007F1E11F831F8, c:0000000000000000, ft:0 eof:0, client: 85.193.34.174, server: smalljobs.cz, request: "GET /8 HTTP/1.1", host: "smalljobs.cz"
nginx                  | 2024/11/08 17:09:28 [error] 7#7: *1 attempt to receive data on a closed socket: u:00007F1E11F831F8, c:0000000000000000, ft:0 eof:0, client: 85.193.34.174, server: smalljobs.cz, request: "GET /8 HTTP/1.1", host: "smalljobs.cz"
nginx                  | 2024/11/08 17:09:28 [error] 7#7: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: content_by_lua(/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:60):24: receive_message: failed to get type: closed
nginx                  | stack traceback:
nginx                  | coroutine 0:
nginx                  |    [C]: in function 'assert'
nginx                  |    content_by_lua(/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:60):24: in main chunk, client: 85.193.34.174, server: smalljobs.cz, request: "GET /8 HTTP/1.1", host: "smalljobs.cz"

WHAT I TRIED:

Changing my Nginx container to network_mode: host - failed in beging:
upstream smalljobsserver {
server smalljobsserver:3034; << smalljobsserver not found
}
connecting through 127.0.0.1 host and resolver 8.8.8.8 or GOOGLE DNS, or failed with no possible to send connection out

WHAT I WANT
Get data from db depend on /:id from URL. Anyhow secured, not spoof able

after a days of try I found simplest solution, using sh & psql & Lua:
content is html of file
                        local handle = io.popen("/etc/nginx/fetchData.sh " .. id)
                        local resp = handle:read("*a")
                        handle:close()

                        if not resp then
                            ngx.say(content)
                            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
                        end
                        
                        -- A simple pattern-based approach
                        local data = {}
                        for key, value in resp:gmatch('%"(.-)"%s*:%s*"([^"]-)"') do
                            data[key] = value
                        end

                        if not data then
                            ngx.say(content)
                            ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_OK)
                        end

                        content = content:gsub("TITLEMETATAG", data.title or "Default Title")
                        content = content:gsub("DESCRIPTIONMETATAG", data.descriptionShort or "Default description")
                        content = content:gsub("URLMETATAG", "https://smalljobs.cz/" .. id)
                        content = content:gsub("LOCATIONMETATAG", data.city or "")
                        content = content:gsub("PRICEMETATAG", data.offeredPrice or "")
                        ngx.say(content)


in my .sh file:
# Sanitize ID by escaping any single quotes (prevent SQL injection)
... IMPORTANT TO SANITIZE ... << GIVE A SEARCH ON INTERNET

# Run the PostgreSQL query and capture the output
RESULT=$(PGPASSWORD="$DB_PASSWORD" psql -h "$DB_HOST" -p "$DB_PORT" -U "$DB_USER" -d "$DB_NAME" -t -A -c "SELECT * FROM \"MY_TAB\" WHERE id = '$ID';")

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "{\"error\": \"Failed to execute query\"}"
  exit 1
fi

# Extract individual columns from RESULT using `awk`
IFS='|' read -r id description title <<< "$RESULT"

# Return the result in JSON format with key-value pairs
echo "{
  \"id\": \"$id\",
  \"description\": \"$description\",
  \"title\": \"$title\"
}"

